# Traditional notation option?

Tags: latex, custom-notation, traditional-form

I have a simple prime counting function using the `Cyclotomic` function.

```
myPi[n_] := Sum[KroneckerDelta[Cyclotomic[m, 1], m], {m, 1, n}]  
myPi[1001] == PrimePi[1001]
```

When I `copy as latex` I get,
$$\text{myPi} n\text{:=}\sum _{m=1}^n \delta _{C_m(1),m},
$$
where I have to place $()$ around the $n$, which seems to be a bug.

However, my question: Is there an option to cause the $C$ to become the traditional $\Phi$, as below?

$$\text{myPi}(n)\text{:=}\sum _{m=1}^n \delta _{\Phi_m(1),m}.$$

Comment: How are you using the Latex code? Are you not copying it to your Latex editor to use?  Then why not simply in the editor, do global search and replace?  Replace `C_m` with `\Phi_m` and that should do it?

Comment: @Nasser, that's what I do. This also occurs with a few other symbols, so I was wondering if I could set an option to use a substiture character.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do it in Mathematica itself (I mean to tell it to change how the Latex is generated), but I could be wrong. I always did the replacements in the Latex editor each time.

Comment: @Nasser, I was thinking there might be a symbol synonym list to select from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define the function

```
\[CapitalPhi][m_, k_] := Cyclotomic[m, k]
```

Then write your comparision as

```
myPi[n_] := Sum[KroneckerDelta[\[CapitalPhi][m, 1], m], {m, 1, n}]
myPi[1001] == PrimePi[1001]

(* Out[505]= True *)
```

Copying the first line as Latex gives the string

```
\text{myPi}(\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\sum _{m=1}^n \delta _{\Phi (m,1),m}
```

which shows up as

$$\text{myPi}(\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\sum _{m=1}^n \delta _{\Phi (m,1),m}$$

Comment: I didn't think about puting a wrapper around it! +1

Answer (score 5):

Conversion to $\TeX$ internally uses `TraditionalForm` boxes. $C$ is already used there:

```
Cyclotomic[m, 1] // TraditionalForm
```

> $ C_m(1) $

In definition of `Cyclotomic`:

```
?? Cyclotomic
(* ...
Cyclotomic/:MakeBoxes[Cyclotomic[BoxForm`a$_,BoxForm`b$_],TraditionalForm]/;BoxForm`sufficientVersionQ[6.1]:=
    TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[BoxForm`a$,TraditionalForm],MakeBoxes[BoxForm`b$,TraditionalForm]},Cyclotomic]
... *)
```

we can see that conversion to `TraditionalForm` boxes use a `TemplateBox` with `"Cyclotomic"` style.

Inspection of `"Cyclotomic"` style:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Cyclotomic"}]
(* {TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction ->
        (RowBox[{SubscriptBox["C", #1], "(", #2, ")"}] &),
    TemplateBoxOptionsTooltip -> Automatic} *)
```

reveals `DisplayFunction`, that is used by `TemplateBox` with this style, containing `"C"` that you'd like to change.

---

You can create your own StyleSheet with modified `DisplayFunction`:

```
Export[
    FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "MyCyclotomic.nb"},
    Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Cyclotomic"], TemplateBoxOptions -> {
            DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{SubscriptBox["Φ", #], "(", #2, ")"}] &),
            Tooltip -> Automatic
        }]
    }, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
]
(* ".../.Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/MyCyclotomic.nb" *)
```

and set it as StyleSheet of current notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "MyCyclotomic.nb"]
```

Now any conversion to $\TeX$ of `Cyclotomic` will give expected `Φ`:

```
Cyclotomic[m, 1] // TeXForm
(* \Phi _m(1) *)
```

Comment: +1, Very nice! Is this something that would carry on to child notebooks?

Comment: @FredKline `Export` step creates stylesheet notebook in place that is searched by *Mathematica*, so it should be "avalilable" for all notebooks. `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ...]` sets this stylesheet permanently, but only for currently used notebook (you could also do it by using menu `Format` > `Stylesheet` > `MyCyclotomic`). If you want to use this stylesheet, by default, in other notebooks, you could change value of `DefaultStyleDefinitions` option.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this slight workaround, or some elements of it, will be useful.
First, save your expression in a variable `myTradFcn`

```
myTradFcn = TraditionalForm@Style[#, Black] &@ HoldForm[Sum[KroneckerDelta[Cyclotomic[m, 1], m], {m, 1, n}]]
```

[image]

Then `ReplaceAll` to swap the `C` for a `φ`

```
myNewFcn = myTradFcn /. {Cyclotomic[a_, b_] -> HoldForm[Subscript[Φ, a][b]]}
```

[image]

Once you've done this, you can `Export` it in png format (to produce the output as shown above)

```
tempimage = Rasterize[
  myNewFcn,
  RasterSize -> 1600, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, ImageFormattingWidth -> 1600];
Export[
  "~/Desktop/image.png", 
  Framed[tempimage, FrameMargins -> 8, FrameStyle -> Directive[White]]]
```

or `Export` as `"TeX"`

```
Export[
  "~/Desktop/texformula",
    Framed[myNewFcn, FrameMargins -> 8, FrameStyle -> Directive[White]], "TeX"]
```

[image]

When I open the resulting `texformula` file in LaTeX and typeset, this last image displays with the summation indices in a compact form, but in LaTeX you can replace `\sum_{m=1}^n` with `\sum\limits_{m=1}^n` to force the indices to be above and below the summation sign.

Comment: (at)zentient Good idea to work in TraditionalForm[] variables. But instead of using the bypass Export you can simply CopyAsLatex the output of MyNewFcn.